# Chid Div With Absolute Positioning Overlaps Content in Parent

Tags: css, wordpress, css-position

Per this WordPress [site](http://www.gridviper.com/sweaters/). I have a child div inside a parent with the following styles that forces it to full browser width even though the parent has a defined centered width. The following are the child's styles

```
.slider-controller 
{
position: absolute; 
width: 100%; 
left: 0; 
right: 0; 
top: 100; 
}
```

I have a plugin called Metaslider that prints a full browser width slideshow inside this child div.  The problem occurs when I place content in the parent div.  The child's variable height overlaps the content in the parent when the browser width is modified.  How would you approach making this content stay below the child regardless of browser width? 
I appreciate any thoughts you may have on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to ascertain exactly what the slideshow height is, but since:

- you want the first paragraph in `<main>` to always begin just below the slideshow
- the slideshow has a consistent relative height (relative to viewport
  width)

The following style declaration - using *viewport width units* (`vw`) - will take both of these considerations into account:

```
main p:first-of-type {margin-top: 48vw;}
```

Comment: Your Kung Foo is strong Rounin! Thank you so much.  Wow!  You just woke me up with the usage of units. Fantastic....

Comment: You're most welcome @ScottFichter. (I wasn't using viewport units before early 2016 either.) Browser support for `vw` and `vh` is almost universal and support for `vmin` and `vmax` is widespread. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units